# PHP-activerecord - relation has_many (users, groups, users_groups)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, phpactiverecord

I want to do this on my view but it´s not working:

```
<?php echo $user->group->name;?>
```

I have 3 tables

```
- users (id, name)
- groups (id, name)
- users_groups (id, user_id, group_id)
```

I have 2 models

```
class User extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('group', 'through' => 'users_groups')
    );
}

class Group extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $has_many = array(
        array('users' , 'through' => 'users_groups')
    );
}
```

My models are wrong or miss something?  I need another model users_groups? If is yes, how would be called?

I need help, i don´t find the correct way.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, in the users_groups table are the relation.

Comment: you can get the group name of user in user class, also can get list of users of group in group class

Comment: @mohammadfalahat I use php-activerecord, i want to do this with associations, not with code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $has_many = array(
    array('groups', 'through' => 'usersgroups', 'order'=>'id asc'),
        array('usersgroups')
    );
}


class Group extends ActiveRecord\Model 
{
    static $has_many = array(
        array('users' , 'through' => 'usersgroups'),
        array('usersgroups')
    );
}

class UsersGroup extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    static $table_name = 'users_groups';

    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('user'),
        array('group')
    );
}
```

The problem was with the name of the of third model (UsersGroup in singular)

Answer (score 0):

```
class User extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
    function get_group($user_id){
        $query = "SELECT name FROM groups 
                  LEFT JOIN users_groups ON (groups.id=users_groups.group_id)
                  LEFT JOIN users ON (users_groups.user_id=users.id)";
        $this->group = mysql_fetch_object($query);
    }
}
```

add this function to your User function

Comment: I need to do with php-activerecord relations (my problem is that my models don´t have the appropriate associations)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is in the [manual](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Associations). This is an example of many-to-many association, that you are trying to implement. In this case groups is orders and users_groups is payments.

[image]

```
 class Order extends ActiveRecord\Model {
   static $has_many = array(
     array('payments'),
     array('users', 'through' => 'payments')
   );
 }

 class Payment extends ActiveRecord\Model {
   static $belongs_to = array(
     array('user'),
     array('order')
   );
 }

 class User extends ActiveRecord\Model {
   static $has_many = array(
    array('payments')
   );
 }

 $order = Order::first();
 # direct access to users
 print_r($order->users); # will print an array of User object
```

Comment: I followed this manual without luck, my problem was with the third model, his name and associations.